# How to get images in control loop for visual servoing in Drake simulation?

Tags: drake

I would like to set up a visual servoing scenario in Drake (I'm using `pydrake`), and don't fully understand how I should wire up the ports of my `LeafSystem` to be able to read the images in the control loop.

Currently I have the following structure for my joint position controller:

```py
class MyController(LeafSystem):

    def __init__(self, n_joints=7):
        super().__init__()

        self.position_cmd_port = self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "my_command",
            BasicVector(2 * n_joints),
            self._get_position_command
        )

    def _get_position_command(self, context, command_vec):        
        # TODO I need to get an RGB image here from my camera
        rgb_img = None

        command = command_vec.get_mutable_value()
        # TODO Do the image processing and control command computation
        # needed here to populate joint position (and/or velocity) command
```

I saw that there's a [`DeclareImageInputPort`](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.sensors.html?highlight=imageinput#pydrake.systems.sensors.ImageWriter.DeclareImageInputPort) function on `pydrake.systems.sensors.ImageWriter`, and since `ImageWriter` has `LeafSystem` as a base class, maybe I can just have my controller extend `ImageWriter`, i.e. define

```py
class MyController(ImageWriter):
   ...
```

And then use the `DeclareImageInputPort` similar to how I define my output port for the position command, and wire it up to my camera so that I could grab the image inside `_get_position_command` in the control loop. Conceptually that feels strange, implementing a controller that extends `ImageWriter`, is there a better way to get the images inside my control loop?

I'd appreciate any guidance on if this seems the best route to go, if there's a better way, or if there's maybe an example sitting around somewhere that does visual servoing in Drake that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Don't extend ImageWriter. I will try to circle back later with a fully-worked answer. For now see https://drake.mit.edu/#tutorials tutorial for "Authoring Leaf Systems" at "Abstract-valued Ports". The type you want to declare for the controller input port is something like pydrake.systems.sensors.ImageRgba8U. That should allow you to connect sensor output port to the controller input port directly.

Comment: I see, thank you! I had searched `DeclareImageInputPort` in the pydrake documentation since that seemed a natural variant of `DeclareVectorInputPort` that I was using, and only found it on `ImageWriter`. I'm still learning the details of constructing the ports myself, but that tutorial is really helpful. Thanks! I will give this a try.